# HttpResponse response = client.execute(request); fails with Https URL (connection refused) ,

Tags: java, selenium, https

I can't get this to work with HTTPS. It gives me: *Connection refused*. Works consistently with HTTP.

```
//Method creates a httpPost such as a json file

public static void createRequest(StringEntity params, String[][] headers, String url) {

    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

    try {

        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);

        for(String[] header: headers) {
            request.addHeader(header[0], header[1]);
        }
        request.setEntity(params);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

        System.out.println(response.toString());

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work in a browser?

Comment: Yes - using poostman

Answer (score 0):

Can you try providing proxy?

```
httpclient.getParams().setParameter("proxyportvalue",proxy);
```